# Will go build pack unused external dependencies?

Tags: go, go-modules, go-build

I have a `lib` module planned to be used across projects. It will depend on many other modules.

But not all the projects will use functions provided by `lib`. I'm wondering if a project only depends on `b/func B` provided by `lib`, will it pack all the unused modules during project's build?

I understand go's smallest build unit is a pkg. In such case will `ext-depency A module` and `ext-depency N module` pack it into my `project module` binary?

How can I test this?

[image]

Comment: `ext-depency N module`? You mean `package`?

Comment: no, it's another go module

Comment: Whatever module or package, go will strip unused thing when it building.

Answer (score 2):

> But not all the projects will use functions provided by lib. I'm wondering if a project only depends on b/func B provided by lib, will it pack all the unused modules during project's build?

No.

> I understand go's smallest build unit is a pkg. In such case will ext-depency A module and ext-depency N module pack it into my project module binary?

No idea what you are asking.

> How can I test this?

Inspect the generated binary. (No, don't do that).

Honestly, this is a 100% non problem. Nothing to see or worry here. Forget all this. The generated binary contains what is necessary and nothing else. Unused stuff is stripped during linking.